# preventing intellisense suggestion boxes from stealing focus for up/down arrows

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellisense

When I type "std::" in Visual Studio, I get a list of the members of the std namespace in an Intellisense dropdown. That's good; I like that. Then, pressing the down key will start to cycle through the elements in the dropdown.

But usually, when I press the down key with a dropdown active, I don't want to browse through the dropdown; I want to look at the next line of code. Is there a way to make that the default behavior?

I am aware that shift+down will perform the desired function (move to the next line).

Comment: Not exactly what you were looking for, but un-checking (tools->options->text-Editor->C/C++->General->Statement completion->*parameter information*) got rid of some extra such dropdown boxes which were giving me a headache, such as showing extra constructor templates (but doesn't change behavior for std:: or things like that).